# Django rest framework sql raw query from another host

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

I have two database with different connection, 1st is the default database and 2nd is for data only.

1st DB:

```
Host:0.0.0.0
port:5822
dbname:DBone
user:postgres
password:user:postgres
```

2nd DB:

```
Host:0.0.0.0
port:5842
dbname:DBtwo
user:postgres
password:user:postgres
```

1st database the main database, I want to query data from 2nd database under views.py (request) Im using Django RestFrameworks now. I want to raw query from another host connection, how to do that?

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request):
    data = DBtwo.objects.raw(SELECT current from DBtwo WHERE name ='Test' AND gender ='M' AND age ='20')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple databases, then you can query the needed one with a method `using`, simply pass the name of the database you need, e.g.:

```py
DBtwo.objects.using(<DB_NAME>).raw(<RAW SQL QUERY>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation goes into detail on how to use multiple databases:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/

I would also recommend using the Django ORM rather than raw SQL queries:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/